# Bootstrap dropdown not working but used to

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap menu whith a dropdown. It used to work but something happened. I click on it and nothing happens.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="{% if this.page.id == 'home' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{ 'home'|page }}">Főoldal</a></li>
    {% if user %}
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ user.name }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ 'new-post'|page}}">New post</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a data-request="onLogout" data-request-data="redirect: '/good-bye'">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class=""><a href="{{ 'auth'|page }}">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

At the bottom:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'|theme }}"></script>
```

Update: Checked with the original example but still not working so the problem is somewhere in the js part. But the JS is there.

Comment: whats the error that you getting ? on click

Comment: What does 'nothing happens' mean?

Comment: I click on it and nothing happens. No error, nothing changes

Comment: Try replacing the bootstrap file path with a [CDN link](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and check if its working.

Comment: Tried that but still nothing. I checked both and the js is there.

Comment: check your browser console for javascript errors

Comment: As dev said check any errors in console. And did you add the bootstrap CSS?

Comment: There are no errors, and i added the bootstrap css most of my page is using it without problem.

Comment: Try to bind show event and see if it fires when you click. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/7hh5d1qs/)

Answer (score 1):

u missed a `</ul>` after `{% endif %}`
see http://jsfiddle.net/26vpc9o3/1/

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="{% if this.page.id == 'home' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{ 'home'|page }}">Főoldal</a></li>
{% if user %}
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ user.name }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">      
        <li><a href="{{ 'new-post'|page}}">New post</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a data-request="onLogout" data-request-data="redirect: '/good-bye'">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class=""><a href="{{ 'auth'|page }}">Login</a></li> 
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: check your console for errors. Might be the path you giving for bootstrap | theme is not correct

Comment: Everything is there. Double checked them. The order is good too when im including the js.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The bootstrap js was included twice. I didnt noticed it because the bootstrap wasnt in its name.